# Pandas: Mean of a column between change of condition in second column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Say I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randint(1, 10, size=(10,2))

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['x1', 'x2'])
df['switch'] = [1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1]
index_ = pd.date_range('2022-01-17 13:00:00', periods=10, freq='5s')
df.index = index_.rename('Time')
```

resulting in:

```
                    x1  x2  switch
Time            
2022-01-17 13:00:00 2   6   1
2022-01-17 13:00:05 9   8   1
2022-01-17 13:00:10 4   9   0
2022-01-17 13:00:15 5   6   0
2022-01-17 13:00:20 4   9   1
2022-01-17 13:00:25 6   7   1
2022-01-17 13:00:30 4   6   0
2022-01-17 13:00:35 2   3   0
2022-01-17 13:00:40 4   9   1
2022-01-17 13:00:45 5   2   1
```

I'm looking for a way of getting the start time, end time, and means of x1 & x2 for each block where the switch value is 1.

So here (for example):

Start: 2022-01-17 13:00:00

End: 2022-01-17 13:00:05

x1 mean: 5.5

x2 mean: 7

I have no idea how to both detect the change in the switch column and then also to build the mean from the values occurring between the change and return the times at which the change in the switch column occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`groupby`+`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) with a custom group:

```
df2 = df.reset_index()
df2['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Time'])

(df2[df2['switch'].eq(1)]               # keep only rows with switch 1
 .groupby(df2['switch'].ne(1).cumsum()) # group by consecutive 1s
 .agg({'x1': 'mean', 'x2': 'mean', 'Time': ('min', 'max')})
)
```

output:

```
         x1   x2                Time                    
       mean mean                 min                 max
switch                                                  
0       7.5  4.0 2022-01-17 13:00:00 2022-01-17 13:00:05
2       3.0  4.5 2022-01-17 13:00:20 2022-01-17 13:00:25
4       6.0  3.5 2022-01-17 13:00:40 2022-01-17 13:00:45
```

###### alternative output:

```
df2 = df.reset_index()
df2['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Time'])

(df2[df2['switch'].eq(1)]
 .groupby(df2['switch'].ne(1).cumsum())
 .agg(avg_x1=('x1', 'mean'),
      avg_x2=('x2', 'mean'),
      start=('Time', 'min'),
      end=('Time', 'max'))
 .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

output:

```
   avg_x1  avg_x2               start                 end
0     7.5     4.0 2022-01-17 13:00:00 2022-01-17 13:00:05
1     3.0     4.5 2022-01-17 13:00:20 2022-01-17 13:00:25
2     6.0     3.5 2022-01-17 13:00:40 2022-01-17 13:00:45
```

Comment: I've realized that I need to calculate back from the end time for a period and take the mean over that, so if switch changes from 1 to 0, I need the means over the last 5sec, for example. Is it possible to adapt this or should I ask another question?

Comment: @Andy the grouping logic will be probably different, ask a new one

Comment: Could you explain how the grouping by consecutive 1s works? I don't really understand that part

Comment: @Andy start with `df2['switch'].ne(1)` this give a boolean True every time there is **not** a 1. True is equivalent to 1 in python (and False to 0). So for an input of `[0 1 1 0 0 1 1]` you have an array like `[T F F T T F F]` equivalent to `[1 0 0 1 1 0 0]`. Then take the cumulated sum (`cumsum`), this gives `[1 1 1 2 3 3 3]`. Now the first two 1s are in group `1`, the next two in group `3` (the exact number does not matter here). As we previously sliced to keep only the 1s now each stretch is its own group. Is this clear?

Comment: This is why in my first code, there is a "weird" index of 0/2/4, those are the group names as I did not reset the index ;)