# Pandas: Mean of columns over timespan after a conditon change in other column

Tags: python, pandas

(this is related to  [Pandas: Mean of a column between change of condition in second column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71155640/pandas-mean-of-a-column-between-change-of-condition-in-second-column))

Say I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randint(1, 10, size=(10,2))

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['x1', 'x2'])
df['switch'] = [1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1]
index_ = pd.date_range('2022-01-17 13:00:00', periods=10, freq='5s')
df.index = index_.rename('Time')
```

resulting in:

```
                    x1  x2  switch
Time            
2022-01-17 13:00:00 2   6   1
2022-01-17 13:00:05 9   8   1
2022-01-17 13:00:10 4   9   0
2022-01-17 13:00:15 5   6   0
2022-01-17 13:00:20 4   9   1
2022-01-17 13:00:25 6   7   1
2022-01-17 13:00:30 4   6   0
2022-01-17 13:00:35 2   3   0
2022-01-17 13:00:40 4   9   1
2022-01-17 13:00:45 5   2   1
```

I'm looking for a way of getting the means of x1 & x2, based on the end time, for each block where the switch value is 1. After the switch value changes from 1 to 0, the means of x1 & x2 should be calculated for the previous 5 seconds, and place these values preferably in a new dataframe, returning something like:

Start: 2022-01-17 13:00:00

End: 2022-01-17 13:00:05

x1 mean: 5.5

x2 mean: 7

Comment: What do you exactly mean by calculating the previous 5 seconds? For example, what would happen if you are interested in getting the first row which has no previous value?

Comment: The switch value shows when a switch was turned on. A measurement is then taken for a period of time and the switch turned off. The start of the measurement does not always match with the switch activation. So if the switch value changes to one at t_0 until t_1. The measurement has a standard length but t_1 - t_0 may be longer than that. So I need to find the end point of the measurement, calculate the start point by subtracting the length of the measurement and get the mean of the column values between those points, for each end point

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you can simply use a function such as what follows:

```py
def getTmean(fTime, lTime, df):
  if "Time" not in df.columns:
    df.reset_index(inplace=True)
  if "Time" not in df.columns:
    raise ValueError("No time index in dataframe")
  
  df["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Time"])
  dfSelected = df[(df["Time"] >= fTime) & (df["Time"] <= lTime) & (df["switch"] == 1)]
  return (dfSelected["x1"].mean(), dfSelected["x2"].mean())
getTmean("2022-01-17 13:00:00", "2022-01-17 13:00:05", df)
```

In your case, it results in:

```
(5.5, 7.0)
```

##### Explanation

The function `getTmean()` gets three arguments:

- `fTime`, which is the start time in string
- `lTime`, which is the end time in string
- `df`, which is the dataframe

Note that the dataframe should at least have a column named `Time` containing the date values.

Comment: Thank you! It's not exactly what I was looking for as I wanted the start and end times to be found for me, but coupled with the answer that I linked to in the question it solved my problem